# Cassandra nodetool ring Output

Tags: cassandra

Anyone know how to interpret the output of nodetool ring?
I have (simplified):

```
Address         Token                                       
                9182993262602236459                         
192.168.21.12   -9204505500292705697       
192.168.21.12   9165421524799589290    

192.168.21.15   -9203572587682667203       
192.168.21.15   9184337856869907559      

192.168.21.17   -9190549423393805123                                              
192.168.21.17   9220038887751192440  

192.168.21.6    -9182540573275734539                                               
192.168.21.6    9220499195115610413   

192.168.21.14   -9164606363409196897                                                 
192.168.21.14   9203325607997193706        

192.168.21.13   -9145474564679737313                                            
192.168.21.13   9200539449471221894                         

192.168.21.10   -9131681360724857397                                              
192.168.21.10   9041062359149913777   

192.168.21.7    -9131135121177816157                                              
192.168.21.7    9180453867888441415    

192.168.21.11   -9106817332529463554                                             
192.168.21.11   9182993262602236459
```

This is the output of nodetool ring keeping only the largest and smallest token value for all vnodes on each node.
I thought the token value was the lowest token in the range for that vnode? In that case I would expect to see Int64.MinValue (-9,223,372,036,854,775,807), which isn't there. I also don't see Int64.MaxValue, so could it be that the token value is a mid-point?

Any help appreciated thanks.

Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nodetool ring outputs all tokens for that node.  If a node had token Int64.MinValue or Int64.MaxValue it would print it.

You probably want to use nodetool status instead, this gives most of the data that used to be available from nodetool ring before vnodes.  You only need nodetool ring if you really want to see all nodes' tokens.

Comment: I'm using nodetool ring because I actually do want to see the tokens. nodetool status is used for a completely different purpose. I'm also not sure what you mean by your first statement. I'm seeing 256 tokens per node, which corresponds to the number vnodes. My question was how do these token 'values' correspond to the actual stored token ranges e.g. if I have two vnodes with tokens 100 and 200 does that mean that the first vnode stores keys 100-199 i.e. 100 is the low point in the range or 50-149 i.e. 100 is the midpoint in the range.

Comment: To find the replicas for SimpleStrategy with replication factor N, take the hash, t, of the key.  Then find the N distinct nodes with smallest tokens greater than or equal to t.  So in your example the vnode with token 200 will store keys that hash to [101,200] if N=1.

Comment: That's what I was looking for thanks... Actually on second thought if it's partitioned on smallest hash >= token then shouldn't I be seeing Int64.MinValue? My smallest token is -9204505500292705697, so what happens to hashes between -9,204,505,500,292,705,697 and -9,223,372,036,854,775,808?!

Comment: There is an implicit wrap around. If you had vnodes with tokens MIN+10 and MAX-10, then keys that hash to [MAX-9,MAX] or [MIN,MIN+10] will be stored on the vnode that has token MIN+10.  So in your case the hashes in [-9223372036854775808,-9204505500292705697] are stored on the vnode with token -9204505500292705697 as well as the keys with the largest tokens.